# why is DIV position different from browser to another?

Tags: html, css

i'm creating a simple page which have the following look

[image]

so as it shows in IE the the top div (the tabs div) is perfectly viewed with the down (body) div but in google chrome the top div (the tabs div) is one or two pixels to the right and i don't know why?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML and CSS? Without it, we can't be of much help to you.

Comment: What version of IE or Google Chrome? This is caused by a difference between Webkit and Trident's implementations of unordered lists (which I am guessing you are using for the navigation links).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend boning up on the CSS Box Model for the different browser types.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/

Your problem is the padding or the border in navigation bar section.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the beginning of your css styles

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: While this might work for testing purposes, the asterisk reset should never be implemented in production. Use a proper reset stylesheet like https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/ or http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/